# Insert new segment when apache druid already have more them 1M segments

Tags: druid

I have an apache druid cluster setup with 1 master, 2 data Server and 1 query server and apache cassandra as deep storage. Now my druid setup has more then 1 million segment already and 15 different data source. 
When ever I try to insert new data it sometimes give me OutofMemeory exception.

What I want to do is, when I want to insert new data I want to mark some of the segments `unused`. Here is the catch, according to [druid doc](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/data-management.html#deleting-data) if I mark any segment as unused druid will delete it from deep storage. I don't want that. After inserting new data I want to re-enable the `unused` segments. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Druid doesn't delete `unused`segments from deep storage until you run a `kill task`. Read [here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-delete-data.html)

So basically, there are 2 steps to permanently delete a particular segment: `disable segment` by either **segment-interval** or **segmentId** and then post a `kill task` on druid server

2. As long as a segment is only disabled, it can be reloaded. To reload unused segments post a similar task to the following on druid server:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{ "interval" :
"interval-of-segment" }' http://localhost:8081/druid/coordinator/v1/datasources/datasourcename/markUsed
```

Comment: This was my mistake, I didn't go through the doc properly.

Comment: glad to help :)